# Continuos loop with user input condition in python?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, user-input

I just learn my first python and try to make a continuous loop that has a user input condition.

```
#Make the calculating func
def data_cal():
    pennies = int(input("What's your pennies?"))
    dollars = pennies // 100
    cents = pennies % 100
    print("You have $", dollars, "and", cents, "cents")
data_cal()
#User input for answer
repeat = input("Do you want to try again?")
answer = ['yes','YES','Yes','y','Y']
#Loop for answer
while repeat in answer
    data_cal()
else: print("Bye then")
```

I was thinking if I can recall repeat after I called data_cal() and, or another if statement

```
…..
while repeat in answer
    data_cal()
    if repeat in answer:
      repeat (#this step I tried to recall repeat, is this possible?, any other way to get around this?)
    else: break
print ("Bye then")
```

Please bear with me, I am very new to programming language and might not express myself very clear. The idea is to call the data_cal() for the first time then, ask for user input -("Do you want to try again?") - if the input is yes then recall data_cal() and then RE ASK ("Do you want to try again?") and repeat the cycle, if the input is no then print("Bye")
Thank you very much!

Comment: you want to continue the program until user enters `'n'` or `'No'`?

Comment: I believe you should be able to just copy the `repeat = input()` line into the loop, after the function call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Make the calculating func
repeat = ""
def data_cal():
    pennies = int(input("What's your pennies?"))
    dollars = pennies // 100
    cents = pennies % 100
    print("You have $", dollars, "and", cents, "cents")
    repeat = input("Do you want to try again?")
    return repeat

repeat = data_cal()
#User input for answer
answer = ['yes','YES','Yes','y','Y']
#Loop for answer

while repeat in answer:
    repeat = data_cal()
else:
    print("Bye then")
```

From the code format you have written, just move the repeat assignment line to data_cal(), and return the value so that you can use that in the while loop.

Comment: And dont forget the colon(:) for the while statement :-)

Comment: No problem :-) Please do upvote the answer if you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

You have to ask the user inside of the `while` loop, if he wants to try again (whatever is done in `data_cal()`). Otherwise the given answer can never change.

```
answer = ['yes','YES','Yes','y','Y']
repeat = 'yes'

#Loop for answer
while repeat in answer
    data_cal()
    repeat = input("Do you want to try again?")
else: print("Bye then")
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense when you didn't define repeat before you call it in while loop, does it? .. correct me if I'm wrong. Ty

Comment: You are absolutely right. You have to give `repeat` a sensible default value, so that you enter the loop. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use continue and breake to control your loop，then you can write like this

```
#Make the calculating func
def data_cal():
    pennies = int(input("What's your pennies?"))
    dollars = pennies // 100
    cents = pennies % 100
    print("You have $", dollars, "and", cents, "cents")

answer = ['yes','YES','Yes','y','Y']
#Loop for answer
while True:
    data_cal()
    repeat = input("Do you want to try again?")
    if repeat in answer:
        data_cal()
        continue
    else:
        print("Bye then")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the while loop inside the function.**

```
#Make the calculating func
    repeat = "yes"
    answer = ['yes','YES','Yes','y','Y']

    def data_cal():
        global repeat
        while repeat in answer:
            pennies = int(input("What's your pennies?"))
            dollars = pennies // 100
            cents = pennies % 100
            print("You have $", dollars, "and", cents, "cents")
            repeat = input("Do you want to try again?")

    data_cal()
    print("Bye then")
```