# what's wrong with my python code in Choosing different function based on user input?

Tags: python, function, beautifulsoup

I have made a script using beautifulsoup in order to get a price from a website. As a whole it works perfectly, cause it gives me the online price. But the problem is that :

1. when I'm choosing another lg which is asked first it doesn't pay attention to the USER input and just works as it wishes to... now I want to know what is wrong with this,
   and another important thing is that:
2. How can I Save the price with date in a text or CSV file...
3. how can I re-run the app with a request of the user?

Here is my code:

```
 #<div class="c-product__seller-price-raw js-price-value">۴,۵۹۵,۰۰۰ </div>

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-1800630/%DA%AF%D9%88%D8%B4%DB%8C-%D9%85%D9%88%D8%A8%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%84-%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%B3%D9%88%D9%86%DA%AF-%D9%85%D8%AF%D9%84-galaxy-a70-sm-a705fnds-%D8%AF%D9%88-%D8%B3%DB%8C%D9%85%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AA-%D8%B8%D8%B1%D9%81%DB%8C%D8%AA-128-%DA%AF%DB%8C%DA%AF%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AA"

user=input("Please select your language, English 'E' or Persian 'P': ")

def Persian_App():
    request= requests.get(html)
    content=request.content
    soup=BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
    element=soup.find("div",{"class":"c-product__seller-price-raw js-price-value"})
    print(" Gheymate Gooshie A70 Dar hale Hazer: ")
    print(element.text.strip())
    print("Anjam Shod!")
    return ("")

def English_App():
    request= requests.get(html)
    content=request.content
    soup=BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
    element=soup.find("div",{"class":"c-product__seller-price-raw js-price-value"})
    print(" The Price of Samsung A70 Serie at the moment is:  ")
    print(element.text.strip())
    print("Done")
    return ("")

if user == "E" or "e":
    print(English_App())    
elif user == "P"or"p":
    print(Persian_App())
else:
    print("Please Enter a correct letter!")
    pass
print(input("Press ANY Key to Exit!"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Question 1

```
if user == "E" or "e":
```

is equivalent in python to:

```
if (user == "E") or "e":
```

and "e" evaluates to `True` so even if `user` is different from "E", the first condition will always be `True` and your code will always execute `English_App`.

To fix your problem:

```
if user in ("E"; "e"):
```

or

```
if user.lower() ==  "e":
```

## Question 2

You need to save the result of your function into a variable like:

```
result = None
if user.lower() == "e":
    result = English_App()
elif user.lower() == "p":
    result  = Persian_App()
else:
    result = "Please Enter a correct letter!"
```

then you can use [the csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to save the result into a file.

## Question 3

You have several possibilities for that. Check for instance:

[Continuos loop with user input condition in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58299483/continuos-loop-with-user-input-condition-in-python)

Comment: It worked Perfectly my friend, thanks for your help. I got my answers... thanks a million.